# Daylight saving issue Nov 04 - 05 in EST location

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

Date difference is zero today. When comparing Nov 04 and Nov 05, rare issue happening only for today.

Code I'm using

```
let dayDiff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from:businessDate , to: today).day!
```

[image]

Ipad date and time set to automatically.
Tried restarting iPad.
Tried setting date to tomorrow and I get date diff 1.

Is there any issues because of changes in day light savings yesterday?
If so, what settings I have to update in order to work it as expected?

Note: We can fix it with code changes, but like to know any iPad settings will fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any timezone that had a change in daylight saving time during that period (such as the in USA), the difference between 2018-11-04 00:00:00 UTC and 2018-11-05 00:00:00 UTC is only 23 hours which is less than 1 day so you get a difference of 0 days.

If you create those dates with midnight local time instead of UTC time, you will get the expected result of 1 day difference.

Or if you use a calendar set to the UTC timezone to calculate the difference, you will get 1 day difference.